# Loop thru XML nodes c# WPF

Tags: xml, loops

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-32"?>
<MailTo>
  <To Name="Boss">
    <name>Name1</name>
    <mail>Name1@Mail.com</mail>
  </To>
  <Cc Name="Trainee">
    <name>Name2</name>
    <mail>Name2@Mail.com</mail>
  </Cc>
  <Cc Name="Manager">
    <name>Name3</name>
    <mail>Name3@Mail.com</mail>
  </Cc>
  <Cc Name="Assistant">
    <name>Name4</name>
    <mail>Name4@Mail.com</mail>
  </Cc>
</MailTo>
```

Code:

```
StringReader Empfänger = new StringReader(smartMail.Properties.Resources.MailtoSimW);

                //Read Medium from xml.
                XmlTextReader xReader = new XmlTextReader(Empfänger);
                while (xReader.Read())
                {
                    if (xReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
                    {
                        var attr = xReader["Name"];

                        if(attr != null && attr == "Boss")
                        {
                            if (xReader.ReadToDescendant("mail"))
                            {
                                xReader.Read();
                                Mailto = xReader.Value;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        else { }
                        if (attr != null && attr == "Trainee")
                        {
                            if (xReader.ReadToDescendant("mail"))
                            {
                                xReader.Read();
                                MailCc = xReader.Value;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
```

My Problem is that it only reads the first node (Boss). I only get empty string back from the others :-(
Is there a better way to just loop thru all nodes?
Is there a problem in the first node "To" and the other "Cc" nodes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok my silly mistake.
Just had to remove the "break;"